# Setar preço de serviço em select

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estou com uma duvida, tenho uma tabela de pedidos id,nome,pedido,valor,data... e em minha página tenho um form com select, gostaria que quando eu selecionasse uma opção ele enviasse para o db o nome do pedido que está nas options deste select e cada option tivesse um valor(R$) que no caso iria para a coluna valor, existiria alguma forma de fazer em uma arvore de if para cada valor?

Comment: voce precisa explicar mais sobre seu problema, esta meio confuso, poderia postar parte do codigo que vc esta fazedo? E qual banco esta usando? Esse option precisa vir preenchido com base em dados do banco?

Comment: O que você esteve tentando @SamuelAma?

Answer (score 1):

Cada elemento html só pode enviar um único valor para o seu alvo, para fazer o que está desejando, existem algumas maneiras:

1. Usar outros inputs na pagina (hidden ou text mesmo) e estes receberem valores por javascript com as informações referentes a cada select.
2. Usar um valor em cada option composto, ou seja, o valor, o nome, cada campo que deseja enviar, com alguma forma de separação **Ex: (R$1,00)(meu pedido)(...)** e então separar na outra ponta.